# ASP Classic Update and Add data on database at the same time

Tags: ms-access, asp-classic

I'm using ASP Classic and MS Access database. I have the codes here in ASP Classic where I add data:

```
<%

Dim con, rs, sql

Set con = Server.CreateObject("ADODB.Connection")
Set rs = Server.CreateObject("ADODB.Recordset")

con.open "DRIVER={Microsoft Access Driver (*.mdb)}; DBQ="& Server.MapPath("dbPayroll.mdb") &""
sql="SELECT * FROM tblPayslipRec"

rs.LockType = 3
rs.CursorType = 2

rs.Open sql, con

    rs.AddNew
    rs.fields("ps_date")= request.form("dnt")
    rs.fields("emp_id")= request.form("eid")
    rs.fields("emp_name")= request.form("name")
    rs.Update

    response.redirect "makepayslip2.asp"

rs.Close
SET rs = Nothing
SET con= Nothing
%>
```

And I need to include to the codes above that I will UPDATE one column on the table `tblPayslipRec`.

Is it possible to do it? Please help me if it is.

Comment: Not that I'm a fan of MS Access for Web Applications but you shouldn't be making your MDB file accessible from a path within your website this will come back to bite you later on. Store a configuration value with the physical path to your MDB file outside of the website and give the `IUSR` account rights to this location or use a DSN. At the moment your site is exposing `/dbPayroll.mdb` for the whole world to see (whether it's internet / intranet it is still exposed).

Answer (score 0):

Why don't you just use a standard update query, eg

```
sql = "update tblPayslipRec set name = '"& request.form("name") &"' where id = "& request.form("id")

con.Execute sql
```

I'm assuming here that your primary key field is called "id"

This looks like it's part of an intranet, so sql injection attacks probably aren't a worry, but if this were a public facing webpage I'd strongly advise putting in a function to sanitise your form data before you send it to the database.  Also, you're using an ODBC connection string, which works, but OLEDB connections are probably a better option - eg

```
"PROVIDER=Microsoft.Jet.OLEDB.4.0;DATA SOURCE="& Server.MapPath("dbPayroll.mdb")
```

Answer (score 0):

```
Dim con, rs, sql

Set con = Server.CreateObject("ADODB.Connection")
Set rs = Server.CreateObject("ADODB.Recordset")

con.open "DRIVER={Microsoft Access Driver (*.mdb)}; DBQ="& Server.MapPath("dbPayroll.mdb") &""
sql="SELECT * FROM tblPayslipRec"

rs.LockType = 3
rs.CursorType = 2

rs.Open sql, con
rs.AddNew
rs.fields("ps_date")= request.form("dnt")
rs.fields("emp_id")= request.form("eid")
rs.fields("emp_name")= request.form("name")
rs.Update
rs.close
set rs = nothing 
' Now do your record update

set rs = Server.CreateObject("ADODB.Recordset")
sql="SELECT * FROM tblPayslipRec where id = " & Your_Record_Id
rs.open(sql,conn,1,3) 
if not (rs.eof or rs.bof) then
rs.update
rs("yourField") = "What You Want To Update It With")
rs.update
else
' No record found to update
end if

response.redirect "makepayslip2.asp"

rs.Close
SET rs = Nothing
SET con= Nothing
```